# Visual Studio Emulator for Android, does not show SD Card

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

The VS emulator does not seems to be showing the SD card in the storage menu or through code. any idea how to get it working. even if we go through the SD card menu on the emulator options and provide a folder it doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I first had to 'Pull from SD Card' which seemed to create the required hierarchy under the folder I identified. Then I did a 'Push to SD Card'. Still didn't behave entirely as I expected since no external storage was listed under settings. I just was trying to copy files across and this allowed me to do that.